# How come the same static field has two different ids in dalvik?

Tags: java, android, jvm, dalvik

I'm writing my own toy Dalvik VM, and I can't seem to figure out how dalvik handles inherited static fields.

Consider the following java code:

```java
class Parent { static int parent_int = 10; }
class MyCode extends Parent {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(parent_int + 1);
    }
}
```

When compiled and run with javac and java it prints `11` to the console, as one would expect. However, when this is compiled to dalvik, the `parent_int` value is turned into an `sget` statement to get `field@0000`, whilst in the `<clinit>` method of `Parent` the field id of `parent_int` is `field@0001`.

In my implementation of the Dalvik VM this becomes a problem, since `field@0000` is not initialized, even though the `Parent` class and `field@0001` has been.

How does the Dalvik VM handle this? How does it know that they are related, and should be considered the same? And why have they been turned into two different fields in the first place, when they could just as well be one?

Comment: Technically, static members are _never_ "inherited"; they are simply accessible.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Why do we need multiple ids then? Wouldn't it be easier to just use one id for the parent field and then use that id in the child classes?

Comment: You're correct. Dalvik seems not to be handling this correctly.

Comment: I think you might be missing something here.  According to https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format, a field id refers to a descriptor comprising a definer id, a type id and a name id.  In your example, the reference to the field from the child class would have the parent class as the definer. So in an implementation of the Dalvic VM spec you need to resolve the name ("parent_int") against the parent class to find the field that that the `sget` is operating on.  Or put it another way, the field ids for "parent_id" will be different in the parent and child classes.

Comment: But the point is that you are implementing Java semantics.  If your Dalvik implementation is giving different results to a classic Java implementation ... then you have **most likely** misunderstood the Dalvik spec.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, probably. But except for [source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik), I can not find any good resources/documentation/spec of dalvik (and I can not find anything about static fields in that documentation). And I thought it would be safe for me to expect my java code to behave in the same way in the dalvik VM as in the java VM?

Comment: @StephenC Just read the first comment.. sorry. So you are basically saying that dalvik does not care about the child-class' fields, only about the parent-class' fields (if they exist)? So it would be safe to assume that if a field with the same name and type exists on the parent class, we can just use that one? But what would happen if we had a static field on the sub-class with the same name and only accessed the parent field with super.parent_id in that case?

Comment: It's not that it doesn't care.  It is just that the id in the child is describing a field in the parent.  So the implementation needs to resolve it to the parent class and look at the actual field in the parent classes (runtime) class-level field vector.  Because that's where the actual field values are stored.  In the parent class ... not the child class.  As Chrylis states: static fields are NEVER inherited.

Comment: And no it would not be safe to assume that.  A static field declared in the child class can have the same name as a static field declared in the parent class.   But they are different fields. (If you are going to implement the Dalvlik spec correctly, you need to understand the differences between shadowing, hiding and overriding; see https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java)

Comment: THANK YOU, I think I've got it now. Just one more thing, why would they use two different id's if the field is never inherited, just accessed? Oh, and if you leave an answer I could mark it as correct if you'd like the karma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: The field@0000 and field@0001 are actually different references.

Longer: Let's take this one step at a time:

Decompiling:

```
[tmp]$ dextra  -j -d -D classes.dex
/* 0 */ class   Parent  {
 /** 1 Static Fields (not printed - use -f to print) **/
 /** 2 Direct Methods  **/
 static  void <clinit> () // Class Constructor
    {
    /* # of Registers: 1 */
    /* # of Instructions: 5 */
    /* 0000: Op 1300 0a00       const/16 v0, 0xa */
    v0 = 10; 
    /* 0002: Op 6700 0100       sput v0, ?@1 */
    Parent.parent_int = v0; // (Field@1)
    /* 0004: Op 0e00            return-void  */
    return;

    } // end <clinit>
  void <init> () // Constructor
    {
    /* # of Registers: 1 */
    /* # of Instructions: 4 */
    /* 0000: Op 7010 0500 0000  invoke-direct { v0 } */
    result = java.lang.Object.<init>(v0); // (Method@5(v0))
    /* 0003: Op 0e00            return-void  */
    return;

    } // end <init>
    }  // end class Parent
/* 1 */ class   MyCode extends Parent   {    /** 2 Direct Methods  **/
      void <init> () // Constructor
        {
        /* # of Registers: 1 */
        /* # of Instructions: 4 */
        /* 0000: Op 7010 0300 0000  invoke-direct { v0 } */
        result = Parent.<init>(v0); // (Method@3(v0))
        /* 0003: Op 0e00            return-void  */
        return;

        } // end <init>
     public static  void main (java.lang.String[])
        {
        /* # of Registers: 2 */
        /* # of Instructions: 19 */
        /* 0000: Op 6201 0200       sget-object v1, ?@2 */
        v1 = java.lang.System.out; // (Field@2)
        /* 0002: Op 6000 0000       sget v0, ?@0 */
        v0 = MyCode.parent_int; // (Field@0)
        /* 0004: Op d800 0001       add-int/lit8 v0, 1 */
        v0 +=  1;
        /* 0006: Op 6e20 0400 0100  invoke-virtual { v1, v0 } */
        result = java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.System.out, MyCode.parent_int); // (Method@4(v1, v0))
        /* 0009: Op 6201 0200       sget-object v1, ?@2 */
        v1 = java.lang.System.out; // (Field@2)
        /* 000b: Op 6000 0100       sget v0, ?@1 */
        v0 = Parent.parent_int; // (Field@1)
        /* 000d: Op d800 0001       add-int/lit8 v0, 1 */
        v0 +=  1;
        /* 000f: Op 6e20 0400 0100  invoke-virtual { v1, v0 } */
        result = java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.System.out, Parent.parent_int); // (Method@4(v1, v0))
        /* 0012: Op 0e00            return-void  */
        return;

        } // end main
    }  // end class MyCode
```

(this is your code, but adding another "System.out.println(Parent.parent_int + 1);" after yours)

Now, as you correctly, said, the   of the parent references field1, whereas the main looks at @0. If we display the fields:

```
[tmp]$ dextra  -F classes.dex
         Field (0) Definer: LMyCode; Name: parent_int type: I Flags: 0x0 
         Field (1) Definer: LParent; Name: parent_int type: I Flags: 0x0 
         Field (2) Definer: Ljava/lang/System; Name: out type: Ljava/io/PrintStream; Flags: 0x0
```

we see that field 1 belongs to the Parent, and field 0 to MyCode. Since they are both static, they are owned individually by each class: Upon Dalvik's internal initialization of MyCode (which we don't see, since that's handled at the runtime level, nowadays by cloning the shadow from the .ART), the field reference "static_int" is copied over (from the shadow of the child, not the parent) - but further references to the parent field (like the system.out.println I added) will address the field 1, not 0.

---

EDIT: Note that from the class perspective, there is only field, belonging to the parent:

Class 0: Parent     File: MyCode.java
1 static fields
2 Direct Methods
Class 1: MyCode
extends LParent;       File: MyCode.java
2 Direct Methods

so that "parent_int" is very much owned by the parent class.

---

Note that you always reference the field in the context of this or that object/class, so if not for that optimization. So - Strictly speaking, Dalvik could have collapsed both fields (being identical) - but won't do so since the cost of having this seemingly "duplicate" field isn't high and worth the fast access to the definer.

Comment: It (the field) isn't copied on instantiation either.  There is one and only one `parent_int` field / variable in the entire application that uses those 2 classes.  It has one value at any given time.  And the code in the child classes `main` method is updating it.

Comment: Fully agreed, and edited to make sure the verbiage is clear: (reference from the shadow of the child, not the parent). Didn't mean to imply that the parent class's field itself was copied to the child.  Also showed that parent_int belongs to.. well, the parent. There are, however, TWO "parent_int" references from DEX field table (field 0, and field 1) to same actual field as shown above, which is what question was about.